# How to indent bulletpoints in LaTeX using the Europass CV Package

Tags: latex

I am using the `europasscv` package in LaTeX to create a standardised CV. Attached some sample code below, looking for a solution on how to indent the second bulletpoint (Sorry if this is trivial, I'm new to LaTeX)

```
  \ecvblueitem{Section}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item This is the 1st bulletpoint
    \item This is the 2nd bulletpoint that I would like to be indented to the right of the 1st one
    \item This is the 3rd bulletpoint
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }
```

Comment: please make a [mre]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered nesting the `ecvitemize`?

This:

```
  \ecvblueitem{Section}{
  \begin{ecvitemize}
    \item This is the 1st bulletpoint
    \begin{ecvitemize}
        \item This is the 2nd bulletpoint that I would like to be indented to the right of the 1st one
    \end{ecvitemize}
    \item This is the 3rd bulletpoint
  \end{ecvitemize}
  }
```

results in
[image]